# merge files with datetime using command line

Tags: windows-10, command-line

How can i merge txt file content using command line, and add the date and time of the file.

i have on one directory many txt files with one line only, and i what to merge to one file, and to each line to add the file's time and date.

i have this code to merge:

```
copy *.txt all.txt
```

i have this code to get the date:

```
forfiles /C "cmd /c echo @file @fdate @ftime"
```

but how can i combine them?

Comment: So you are asking how to append each files `@file @fdate @ftime` attributes to the content of each file, correct? You are asking about doing this for each file individually? Please note that if this is the case, once this meta data attribute content is added to each file, then that changes to the date modified attribute to the time you make that change.

Comment: you are right. but i want to add it to write it to a new file. so i will not update the original file.